# Getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined" when returning an object inside a map

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a large text file, that I am looping through so I can format it to a JSON format and then dump it, It works perfectly when I am using `slice` to make the fields start a different position, but as soon as I use `slice`, I get the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`.

This is the current code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
let words;

fs.readFile('dictionary.txt', "utf-8", function(error, contents) {
    if(error) throw error;
    words = contents.split('\n\n');

    words = words.map(value => value.split('\n'))
    .map((column, index) => {
        return {
            id: index+1, 
            word: column[0].slice(10, -1), 
            translation: column[2].slice(7, -1), 
            description: column[3].slice(10, -1)
        }
    });

    fs.writeFileSync('words.json', JSON.stringify(words));
});
```

Keep in mind, when I use `console.log(column[0].slice(10, -1)`, it works perfectly, but when I use it inside the returned object I get that error, the code also works when I remove the `slice` functions, but that is not what I want.

This is an example of what the text file looks like:

```
English : To obliterate
لقی:  هونەر
كوردی: خاپووركردن
وردەكاری: خاپووركردن

English : to one's credit
لقی:  گشتی 
كوردی: جێی شانازی بوون بۆ كەسێك
وردەكاری: جێی شانازی بوون بۆ كەسێك

English : To outline
لقی:  هونەر
كوردی: كورتە نەخشەی كێشا
وردەكاری: كورتە نەخشەی كێشا

English : To paint without a model
لقی:  هونەر
كوردی: وێنەكێشانی بێ مۆدێل
وردەكاری: وێنەكێشانی بێ مۆدێل

English : To paste again
لقی:  هونەر
كوردی: سەرلەنوێ‌ لكاندنەوە
وردەكاری: سەرلەنوێ‌ لكاندنەوە

English : To patronize
لقی:  هونەر
كوردی: چاودێری 
وردەكاری: چاودێری (هونەرمەندێكی) كرد

English : To pick
لقی:  هونەر
كوردی: پیككاری كرد 
وردەكاری: پیككاری كرد (بەردەكەی تەختكرد)

English : To pick out by color
لقی:  هونەر
كوردی: دیاریكردن بەدژایەتی ڕەنگ 
وردەكاری: دیاریكردن بەدژایەتی ڕەنگ 

English : To plane
لقی:  هونەر
كوردی: دەپێكی سازكرد
وردەكاری:  (دەپێك)ی سازكرد
```

Comment: You go from 0 to 2 and 3 for your array indexes, sure you didn't mean to use 0, 1, and 2?

Comment: Your code logic looks OK - something to do with the input file perhaps ... have you tried using console.log to debug what is happening at each step (perhaps there's a trailing `\n\n` and therefore a final empty "block"

Comment: Your code might be a little fragile because it is depending on a very specific format. The text you provided actually works for me with your code, but it breaks if there is an extra newline character at the end.

Comment: @Patrick Evans Yes I am sure, because the [1] index is something that I don't want to include in the returned object.

Comment: And what does `column[3]` show when you log it inside the map()?

Comment: try `words = words.map(value => value.split('\n')).filter(({length}) => length === 4).map((column, index) => {`

Comment: @PatrickEvans - column[3] would be the last line of each "block" of 4 lines

Comment: @PatrickEvans It returns the expected output, nothing unexpected.

Comment: @JaromandaX, That did the trick, can you explain the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there's a `\n\n` at the end of the file add a filter to remove that last invalid "block"

Also, if there's `\n\n\n` or more somewhere in the file, you may want to fix that up too

```
var fs = require('fs');
let words;

fs.readFile('dictionary.txt', "utf-8", function(error, contents) {
    if(error) throw error;
    //               in case there's \n\n\n
    words = contents.replace(/\n{3,}/g, '\n\n').split('\n\n');

    words = words.map(value => value.split('\n'))
    // filter out last block if file ends in \n\n
    .filter(({length}) => length === 4)
    .map((column, index) => {
        return {
            id: index+1, 
            word: column[0].slice(10, -1), 
            translation: column[2].slice(7, -1), 
            description: column[3].slice(10, -1)
        }
    });

    fs.writeFileSync('words.json', JSON.stringify(words));
});
```

This is a little more robust, but still probably not perfect